# How to search in multiple columns in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-vlookup

### I have several columns as follows:

```
Nugegoda  Branch    Nugegoda Branch REF     Malabe Branch   Malabe Branch REF   
102                 2222                    103             33333   
201                 2222                    203             33333   
301                 2222                    303             33333   
401                 2222                    403             33333   
501                 2222                    503             33333
```

### [image]

I have named those ranges as Nugegoda and Malabe. I want to write a VLOOKUP for key 103 searching in both of these ranges together, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you share instead a screenshot of your sheet ? It is hard to see which data correspond to which column .

Comment: I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks! check my updated answer and let me know if it worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try

```
=IFERROR (VLOOKUP(103, {$B$2:$C; $E$2:$F; $H$2:$I}, 2, FALSE))
```

or

```
 =IFERROR (VLOOKUP(L1, {$B$2:$C; $E$2:$F; $H$2:$I}, 2, FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP($L$1,$B$2:$C,2,False),VLOOKUP($L$1,$E$2:$F,2,FALSE))
```

or if you don't want to extra cell reference (L1) use this directly:

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(103,$B$2:$C,2,False),VLOOKUP(103,$E$2:$F,2,FALSE))
```

Essentially you use an if condition with VLOOKUP to check if the value exists in the first range, if not (error) then look for the other range.

[image: Illustration]

**Update based on your comment**.

If you want to look for more than 2 ranges then you can take advantage of the **ISNUMBER()** function. The following searches for **B2:B**, **E2:E** and **H2:H**.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(103,$B$2:$C,2,False)),VLOOKUP(103,$B$2:$C,2,False),IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(103,$E$2:$F,2,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(103,$E$2:$F,2,FALSE),IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(103,$H$2:$I,2,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(103,$H$2:$I,2,FALSE))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I have 3 or more ranges in my worksheet to work, but iferror takes only 2 arguments, is it possible to have many ranges for a vlookup?if so how?